# Unknown number of arguments in currying

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda, currying

Hypothetical situation - can a currying function have an unknown number of arguments (kind of like varargs)
Eg in Python:

```
addByCurrying(1)(2)(3)(4)
```

Should equal 10

```
addByCurrying(5)(6)
```

Should equal 11

How could I implement it?

Comment: You can't do that in the most straightforward way. That would mean that `addByCurrying(1)(2)` is both a number and a function, which isn't possible.

Comment: Have a look at [Is it possible to have currying and variadic function at the same time?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/286231)

Comment: Funny thing I discovered while playing around a bit: `(lambda x: x (x)) ((lambda a: lambda b: lambda c: a (b)) (lambda x: x (x)))` takes an argument and returns a _new_ instance of itself, meaning you can pass as much arguments as you want.

Comment: @Tanner Swett could Church Encodings help on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have currying and variadic function at the same time?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286231/is-it-possible-to-have-currying-and-variadic-function-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @user6245072 Not really. From the perspective of Python, Church encodings aren't numbers; they're functions which represent numbers. Not only that, but their behavior is inconsistent with what vikarjramun is trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently answered [a question on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038358/function-chaining-in-python/39038455#39038455) regarding this exact situation. You *can't* do this with *traditional* functions in Python.

You *can* do this by taking advantage of **callables** though, overloading the `__call__` dunder of an `int` subclass.

In short, return a new instance of your self with the updated value (`+` here):

```
class addByCallable(int):
    def __call__(self, v):
        return type(self)(self + v)
```

Now, you call it and get this 'form' of currying:

```
addByCallable(1)(2)(3)  # 6
```

Which is as close as you can get to doing this in Python.

Comment: Actually this is a great answer! Overloading __call__ is a creative solution that I wouldn't have even thought of. So to do this for another class, I would just define a __call__ function for it, that uses the value of self to return the same class, but also is a function! That's exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: "but also is a function" isn't the exact terminology i'd use :-P. It is also callable, that is, it can *behave* as a function, that's really all we need here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible since there is no way the function could know if it should return a number or a curried function.

There are various way of "cheating" to achieve some thing somewhat like this, for example you could call with no arguments in order to get the number rather than a function:

```
addByCurrying(1)(2) --> curried function
addByCurrying(1)(2)() --> the number 3
```

Which trick is most appropriate depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you define a lambada with an optional parameter? Or one with a default?

Comment: @vikarjramun: Yes.